# Referencing text after script is called within PS1 Script

Tags: powershell, aws-cloudformation

Let's take the PowerShell statement below as an example:

```
powershell.exe c:\temp\windowsbroker.ps1 IIS
```

Is it possible to have it scripted within `windowsbroker.ps1` to check for that IIS string, and if it's present to do a specific install script? The broker script would be intended to install different applications depending on what string followed it when it was called.

This may seem like an odd question, but I've been using CloudFormation to spin up application environments and I'm specifying an "ApplicationStack" parameter that will be referenced at the time when the powershell script is run so it knows which script to run to install the correct application during bootup.

Comment: Can you show your script?  Or, a structure similar to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called argument or parameter handling. In its simplest form PowerShell provides all arguments to a script in the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847768.aspx) `$args`. That would allow you to check for an argument `IIS` like this:

```
if ($args -contains 'iis') {
  # do something
}
```

or like this if you want the check to be case-sensitive (which I wouldn't recommend, since Windows and PowerShell usually aren't):

```
if ($args -ccontains 'IIS') {
  # do something
}
```

However, since apparently you want to use the argument as a switch to trigger specific behavior of your script, there are better, more sophisticated ways of doing this. You could add a `Param()` section at the top of your script and check if the parameter was present in the arguments like this (for a list of things to install):

```
Param(
  [Parameter()]
  [string[]]$Install
)

$Install | ForEach-Object {
  switch ($_) {
    'IIS' {
      # do something
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

or like this (for a single option):

```
Param(
  [switch]$IIS
)

if ($IIS.IsPresent) {
  # do something
}
```

You'd run the script like this:

```
powershell "c:\temp\windowsbroker.ps1" -Install "IIS",...
```

or like this respectively:

```
powershell "c:\temp\windowsbroker.ps1" -IIS
```

Usually I'd prefer switches over parameters with array arguments (unless you have a rather extensive list of options), because with the latter you have to worry about spelling of the array elements, whereas with switches you got a built-in spell check.

Using a `Param()` section will also automatically add a short usage description to your script:

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Help windowsbroker.ps1
windowsbroker.ps1 [-IIS]
```

You can further enhance this online help to your script via [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847834.aspx).

Using parameters has a lot of other advantages on top of that (even though they probably aren't of that much use in your scenario). You can do parameter validation, make parameters mandatory, define default values, read values from the pipeline, make parameters depend on other parameters via parameter sets, and so on. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847824.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847743.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the swift and in-depth advice, as well as the resources for me to continue my own research. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called positional parameters.  You provide the parameters at the beginning of your script:

```
Param(
  [string]$appToInstall
)
```

You could then write your script as follows:

```
switch ($appToInstall){ 
    "IIS" {"Install IIS here"} 
}
```